# How install driver for AcerIconia 500 on Windows 8 and Windows 10 to run device in Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, usb, driver, tablet

Acer does not support Acer Iconia A500 drivers for new windows. This is great problem for Eclipse and Android Studio developers as me, because device is not visible for developing. I was looking for an hours for sollution. But found it ! Hope this helps for other developers with Iconia tablet.

Answer (score 0):

This is step by step sollution:

connect ACER ICONIA 500 to your computer

- connect ACER ICONIA 500 to your computer
- look to the device list, tablet is marked as "unknown device"
- manage the driver and manual set "select driver from list"
- select type of device "Android device"
- select "Google Nexus One ADB Interface"
- Save and thats all, now tablet is visible in Eclipse and Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 now automatically detects Acer Iconia A500 automatically when USB Debugging is enabled on the device.

Happy flashing!